# how to draw a circle shape in excel by using apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I like to draw the circle shape in excel by using apache POI. i have following code. there is not error when i run this code. but when i open the outputted excel file, it say "File error: data may have been lost" and there is not circle shape in outputted excel file.

```
        // Get template file path.
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\template.xls");

        // Create work book.
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(in);

        sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);


        // Draw the circle shape.
        HSSFPatriarch patriarch = (HSSFPatriarch) sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
        HSSFClientAnchor a = new HSSFClientAnchor(1023, 255, 1023, 255, (short)  7,  10, (short) 7, 10);
        HSSFSimpleShape shape1 = patriarch.createSimpleShape(a);
        shape1.setShapeType(HSSFSimpleShape.OBJECT_TYPE_OVAL);
        shape1.setNoFill(true);

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\output.xls");
        wb.write(out);
        out.close();
```

PS: the excel template file ("C:\template.xls") have other figure (shape) already.

thanks

Comment: why do you need template.xls if you are outputting your circle to other excel "output.xls" or am i missing something here ? Also when you open the template.xls is your previous shape present or thats lost too ?

Comment: sorry that is my part of coding. my program need to fill data on existing template file which has full set layout and printer setting. the circle shape is need by condition. When i add new circle shape added by code all of shape on template file are lost thanks

Comment: then why do you need output.xls ?  BTW what about output.xls what does it have ?

Comment: let me explain with example.
"template.xls" is like empty CV form. 
"output.xls" is with filled of full data on that CV (may be more than one sheet)

Comment: Are you using POI 3.9, or an older version? If you're not on 3.9, try upgrading!

Comment: +1 @Gagravarr : thanks alot. it's now ok by upgrading POI version to 3.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is error of POI library that earlier version of 3.9.

There is no error at code. That problem can be solved by upgrading POI version to 3.9

http://poi.apache.org/changes.html

Comment: A GSOC student, Evgeniy Berlog, did a load of work on HSSF drawing over the summer, which fixed a load of issues. 3.9 was the first release to include his work